# How can I make a problem matrix with percentage using matplotlib and seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, graph, seaborn

I want to make this type of graph you see below.
I get that I can make a matrix graph with matplotlib
like so

```
    cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['white','red'])
data = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,],
]
plt.figure(figsize=(9,5))
plt.pcolor(data[::-1],cmap=cmap,edgecolors='k', linewidths=3)
plt.xlabel('Problem') 
plt.ylabel('Particpant')
plt.show()
```

But how would I go about adding percentages to be included in this graph?

[image: I want to make this type of graph]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a secondary x-axis (`ax.twiny()`), using the top axis for the numbering and the bottom axis to show the percentages.

Calling `pcolor` with a list of x and y positions that are 0.5 shifted will put the ticks and tick labels at integer positions. `clip_on=False` makes sure the outer cell borders have the same thickness as the rest. `ax.invert_yaxis()` lets you invert the y axis (so you can use `data` instead of `data[::-1]`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

cmap = ListedColormap(['white', 'orangered'])
data = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(28, 30)) % 2
data[:, 9] = 1  # one full column to simulate 100%
data[:, 11] = 0  # one empty  column to simulate 0%
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 5))
ax.pcolor(np.arange(data.shape[1] + 1) + 0.5, np.arange(data.shape[0] + 1) + 0.5, data,
          cmap=cmap, edgecolors='k', linewidths=3, clip_on=False)
ax.set_yticks(range(1, data.shape[0] + 1))
ax.set_xticks(range(1, data.shape[1] + 1))
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{p:.0f}' for p in data.mean(axis=0) * 100])
ax.invert_yaxis()

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks(range(1, data.shape[1] + 1))
ax2.set_xlabel('Problem')
ax.tick_params(length=0)
ax2.tick_params(length=0)
ax.set_ylabel('Particpant')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolor with shifted cell borders, secondary ax for extra info]

Decreasing the fontsize (or increasing the `figsize`) allows to also show the percentage sign:

```py
ax.set_xticklabels([f'{p:.0f}%' for p in data.mean(axis=0) * 100], fontsize=8)
```